# ROS 2: Controlling Timer Callback Execution Threads

Tags: ros2, multithreading

I have a ROS 2 node that manages a simulation instance. I wish to manage timers for stepping physics and rendering camera views of the simulation environment, where callbacks for either functionality runs on a separate thread.

Rendering leverages OpenGL contexts which need to be managed on a single thread. Therefore, my question is whether it is possible to control timer execution threads in ROS 2 such that I can manage rendering on a single thread. From initial inspection it seems like the MultiThreaded Executor does not provide access to assigning timer callbacks to a specific thread.

Further context can be found [here](https://github.com/google-deepmind/mujoco/issues/1402).